# Laravel 500 post

Tags: laravel, post, http-status-code-500

Уважаемые знатоки, вопрос: почему не отправляются данные на сервер обычным POST`ом?
**web.php**

```
Route::post('/create', 'CourseController@add_course')->middleware('auth');
```

**blade.php**

```
<form id ="create-form" role="form" method="POST" action="/course/create">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
```

**js**

```
$('body').on('submit', '#create-form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr('action');

    var type = $("select[name='type_name'] option:selected").data('id');

    var discription = $("#discription").val();
    var full_description = $("#full_description").val();
    var material_link = $("#xhr_link").val();
    if(discription == "")
        discription = undefined;
    if(full_description == "")
        full_description = undefined;
    if(material_link == "")
        material_link = undefined;
    /* validate form */
    if ($('input[name=free]').prop('checked', false) &&  $('input[name=price]').val().length > 0) {

        var name = $("input[name='course_name']").val();
        var price = $("input[name='price']").val();
        var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();

        $.ajax({
            url:link,
            type:"POST",
            data:{
                "_token":_token,
                "name":name,
                "price":price,
                "type":type,
                "discription":discription,
                "full_description":full_description,
                "material_link":material_link
            },

            success:function() {
                alert('ok');
                //history.pushState(null, null, link);
            },error:function () {
                alert('not-good');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**контроллер**

```
public function add_course(Request $request)
{

    dd('lalala');
}
```

Token со страницы берётся прекрасно, как собственно и все остальные значения. по клику на кнопку при отправлении браузер выдаёт 500 ошибку, дебаггер ларавеля молчит. В логах тоже ничего нет. Тыкните носом где я не прав или может подскажите путь, в котором стоит копать.
PS если их контроллера убрать единственную строчку(оставить его пустым), то ошибка пропадает.
**UPD**  вот ещё интересный момент, хром показывает вот это....[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас роут `/create` а форма передает `/course/create` или у вас роуты сгрупированы ?

Первое - посмотрите существует ли роут выполнив
`php artisan route:list`

Второе - ответ сервера можно увидеть посмотрев вкладку "Network" в development tools.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, руты сгруппированы. В ответ на команду `php artisan route:list` - PHPStorm выдаёт ошибку, что не хватает контроллера RegistrationController. Он я думаю, что это и не так важно, потому что другие POST`ы работают нормально. Network в Chrome пишет, что ошибка 500,а в поле type написано xhr. Наверно это не то, что нужно. Не подскажите как посмотреть ответ от сервера?

Comment: Нашёл что возвращает мне сервер. Там лежит всё, что нужно и (наверно) в необходимом формате. Но ошибка осталась(

Answer (score 0):

Это самая глупая ошибка. Если кому будет интересно - проблема была в dd и всё!!! он просто не могу вывести мне результат. 2 дня потрачены впустую(